# Swift2: How many times a ViewController was called

Tags: swift2

I have a viewcontroller A with a button which calls a viewcontroller B. B has the option to call VC A and VC C also using a button.

So, how can I know the number of times B was called? I need a variable to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Create an int variable in **viewcontroller B** and increment that every time inside the method in B that you're calling from outside B.

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

  var counter: Int = 0

  func methodWhichIsCalledFromOutside() {
    counter++;

    //Do rest of the processing here
  } 
}
```

Comment: hi Hersh, it is a little different, ins't? Ex: VC A call VC B. So, you increment it. VC B call VC A and this counter is zero again, no?

Comment: could layout what exactly you're trying to count? I thought you simply wanted how many times VC B gets called.

Comment: Sure, thanks. First, I need to implement it with buttons. So, let's move on. I have a ViewController A with a login button. When pressed, it calls ViewController B. VC B has several things and a button restart which calls VC A. I need to know how many times it happened.

Comment: Thanks. A global variable was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton instance to keep track of the number of times each `viewController` is called. Here is the basic implementation of the Singleton class

```
class SingletonClass {

    static let sharedInstance = SingletonClass()

    var numTimesVCACalled = 0
    var numTimesVCBCalled = 0
    var numTimesVCCCalled = 0
    // ... so on
}
```

You can then use the sharedInstance of the Singleton class to increment the relevant values (in the `viewDidAppear:`) of each of the controllers and access it anywhere.